# Simple CLI tool for searching

Tags: command-line, locate, file-search

Is there a CLI tool similar to `gnome-search-tool`?
I'm using `locate`, but I'd prefer that it grouped results where directory name is matched. I get a lot of results where the path is matched which is not what I want:

```
/tmp/dir_match/xyz
/tmp/dir_match/xyz2/xyz3
```

It needs to be fast and thus use a search index.

Comment: One should not forget the capabilities of global search from within Emacs using `helm` or `ivy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`locate` is very versatile  can take -r and a regexp pattern, so you can do lots of sophisticated matching. For example, to match directories `a` `a0` `a1` and so on use `'/a[0-9]*/'`.  This will only show directories with files in them since you need the second `/` in the path. To match the directory alone use `$` to anchor the pattern to the end of the path, `'/a[0-9]*$'`.

Note, there are at least 2 versions of the `locate` command, one from [GNU](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Invoking-locate), and one from Redhat (known as mlocate). Use `--version` to find which you have. They differ slightly in the regex style. For example, if we change the above pattern `'/a[0-9]*$'` to use `+` instead of `*` to avoid matching `a` on its own, then mlocate needs `\+` and gnu just `+`.

For example, to match a directory `a` and all underneath it you might use for both versions

```
locate -r '/a\(/\|$\)'
```

For mlocate you might prefex `--regex` which uses extended syntax

```
locate --regex '/a(/|$)'
```

To do the same for gnu locate you would need to add option `--regextype egrep`, for example.

Answer (score 3):

**fzf** is a general-purpose command-line fuzzy finder.

and their github page is https://github.com/junegunn/fzf

Comment: @GAD3R the whole point of this question is to find alternative tools, so a link to the tool is entirely appropriate... Ayyanar, it would nevertheless be interesting to add a bit more information in your answer about the `fsf`’s features. (You can still [edit] your answer to improve it!)

Answer (score 2):

Standard Linux commands for this are :

- `find` command to look for file names, for example:

  - look for files named xyz in `/tmp`

    ```
    $ find /tmp -type f -name xyz
    ```
  - look for directories which name contains 'xyz' in `/tmp`

    ```
    $ find /tmp -type d -name '*xyz*'
    ```
- find and grep commands to search in file contents, for example:

  - find files in `/tmp` which contain xyz

    ```
    $ find /tmp -type f -exec grep -l xyz {} \;
    ```

Comment: I've updated the question. `find` cannot benefit from the search index part of `locate` as far as I know.